# The total number is not calculated and i dont know how to use boolean is valid throw exception

Tags: java, exception, boolean-operations

I have to create a program which accepts the input (number) from user and I need to sum all of the number. If the number is negative, it will not be counted. I have to use boolean isValid method and throw the exception.

```
public class Assignment
{
    private static int num;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Assignment a = new Assignment();
        System.out.println(a.isValid(num));             
    }

    public boolean isValid(int num) throws Exception
    {
        boolean isValid = false;
        int sum = 0;
        int i;
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number:");
                
        try
        {  
            num =scn.nextInt();
            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                if (num>0)
                {
                    num=scn.nextInt();
                    sum+=num;
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println("Enter the number:" +sum);
            }
            return isValid;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do *you* think your current code does?  I suggest trying to comment your code, line by line, and you will quickly find there are lots of mistakes.  I can tell you that right now, your code asks for a bunch of numbers from the user, then prints out false every time because you never touch the `isValid` variable.

Comment: what is the logic of the isValid return value? when should it be false, when true. And what about the sum ? Just print it?

Comment: i actually does not undestand about the isValid variable.. can you expain it ?

Comment: Please explain to us the thought process and the expected output. What should isValid do? I suppose it checks for a valid number of some sort, but what is considered to be a valid number?

Comment: Actually this program will asked the user to enter the number , boolean is valid method is used to check whether the number is is negative or not ,if it is valid which positive ,it will be calculated and sum to other  number.

Comment: the output is just he sum of positive number but have to  go thru porcess to determince wheter the number is valid or not

Answer (score 0):

Thus far I have understood one thing that `boolean isValid()` is not for calculating the sum, instead is for checking the validity of an input. Meaning, we need to pass every input to the function and check whether or not it's a positive number. If yes, return `true`, if no, return `false` and/or throw an exception.
Your `main()` should look like.

```
Assignment a = new Assignment();
int size = scn.nextInt(), sum = 0;
try {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         int input = scn.nextInt();
         if (a.isValid(input)) {
             sum += input;
         }
     }
     System.out.println(sum);
}

catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Your `isValid()` should look like

```
if (num < 0)
    throw new Exception("Negative Number");
return true;
```

Comment: it is ,we have to define first that ,booelan isValid = false?

Comment: @NurhafizaAzman , then instead of returning `true` as it is, you can update `isValid`'s  value to `true` and return it. I don't see any other potential use of `isValid` variable.

Comment: i have enter the input (1,2,3,-9,and 5), ans the output is prompt the number is negative.What sould i do if i only want to calcualte only the  positive number ?

Comment: okayy ,i have already got the answr ,thank you  so much